# CarouselView Xamarin Plugin not working

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xml-namespaces

I am getting the following error:

```
Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'CarouselView' does not exist
in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 
(CS0234) (your project)
```

Using this on the XAML

```
 xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions"
```

Name of the package is: `CarouselView.FormsPlugin`. 
Update......
xaml

Comment: install the plugin?

Comment: Do you use .Net Standard assemblies or pcls? If so - do you have the .net compatibility package installed?

Comment: currently working on PCL - rendering in android . and the nuget installed is CarouselView.FormsPlugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [project documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView), there are several steps you need to do to enable the plugin:

**Install the package via NuGet**

**Initialize the plugin**

On Universal Windows Platform include with Xamarin.Forms initialization:

```cs
List<Assembly> assembliesToInclude = new List<Assembly>();
assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof(CarouselViewRenderer).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, assembliesToInclude);
```

On iOS and Android right after Xamarin.Forms initialization:

```cs
Xamarin.Forms.Init();
CarouselViewRenderer.Init();
```

**Use in XAML**

For XAML usage, you need to include a different namespace (`CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions`) than you noted in the question:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions"
```

And now use as:

```
<controls:CarouselViewControl ...>
```

Comment: Thanks @Martin , I add the initialization part and change the XAML , but I am still getting the same error on android .

Comment: Same error meaning - The type or namespace name 'CarouselView' does not exist
in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms'? This should not happen anymore as long as you use the `CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions` namespace

Comment: I got this error instead : Default constructor not found for type CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Android.CarouselViewRenderer . shouldnt said same error .

Comment: to be honest all I need is to slide 3 images . is any other approach to do this  instead of using this plugin ? Thank you

Comment: This should be the easiest solution unfortunately... There is also a CarouselPage as an alternative, but this takes up the whole page. Have you updated to the latest version of the control?

Comment: It is still quite weird the control does not work in your project as it is one of the most used third party controls for Xamarin.Forms. Could you post the relevant updated code?

Comment: Check this repository I have created - https://github.com/MartinZikmund/Stack-Overflow-2018/tree/master/CarouselViewTest . It is a simple test of the library on a almost empty project. You can see it works quite well. Could you confirm that you have used the same process? Also - are you definitely calling the `CarouselViewRenderer.Init();` inside the `MainActivity.cs` in the Android project?

Comment: yes , I will double check and share the code I have. I will take a look to your repo and update you in a bit. again , Thank you.

Comment: sorry for the late response. so I checked again and I didnt got any of the errors I mentioned before, However. Iam still not able to see the images , which it may be the listview itself. Please check the update section above . Thanks

Comment: I don't see the Update, where should it be?

Comment: please check now

Comment: You are using `{Binding .}`, which is not right, please try using just `{Binding}` instead

Comment: it totally works . those images wasn`t working in the first place , so I added new ones , follow all you said and   the carrousel works. Thank you so much .

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help, happy coding :-)!